# Group differences when dependent variable is nominal

Tags: categorical-data

I have 2 nominal independent variables (2*2 design), and 1 binary (yes/no) dependent variable. I want to see if is there a significant difference between the numbers of No in these 4 conditions. What analysis should I use?

Comment: It seems a kind of problem solvable through binary logistic regression.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a binomial logistic regression would work in that case. In R code it would look something like:

```
glm(binary ~ categorical1 + categorical2, family = "binomial")
```

Comment: Thank you very much!